# How to show two or multiple GADBannerView in one UIVIewController?

Tags: ios, adbannerview

I am using code in my UIViewController for showing GADBannerView as below

```
self.adBanner = [[GADBannerView alloc]
                   initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,
                                            self.view.frame.size.height -300-
                                            GAD_SIZE_320x50.height,
                                            320,
                                            35)];




self.adBanner.delegate = self;
self.adBanner.adUnitID = MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID;
self.adBanner.rootViewController = self;
[self.view addSubview:self.adBanner];
GADRequest * request = [GADRequest request];
request.testing = YES;
[self.adBanner loadRequest:request];
```

This is one adBanner, but is it possible to add other GADBannerView in the same controller. It should look like as below

```
.......................................
.             GADBannerView1          .
.                                     .
.......................................

.......................................
.             GADBannerView2          .
.                                     .
.......................................
```

These both must be shown in one screen, so How can I do this?

Comment: Hi @Duaan did you get any success ? I need the solution for the same case